# Joining lines in C [Strange output not compatible with documentation]

Tags: c, gcc, vim, c-preprocessor

I started coding **C** in vim and I have some problems.

The backslash is intended to join lines but when I try to write:

```
ret\
urn 0;
```

I get

```
return
    0;
```

and when I add spaces before `urn;` it stay like that without join.

```
ret\
   urn 0;
```

it stay like that.

why in the second case I don't get `return 0;` but

```
ret
   urn 0;
```

code:
[image]

CPP output:

[image]

command:

```
gcc -E -Wall -Wextra -Wimplicit -pedantic -std=c99 main.c -o output.i
```

***GCC 5.4, 
Vim 7.4***

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Where is the code that reproduces your problem?

Comment: no need for the code. I don't care about execution of the code I am talking about preprocessor phase !!!

Comment: @Sabrina - There is always need for code. The preprocessor operates on **code**.

Comment: Can someone confirm that behavior in his machine ?

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Simpler test case: `cpp <<<$'foo\\\n bar baz' | grep -v '^#'` (in Bash).  Remove the space to see the tokens concatenated and the following line indented.  It's an interesting effect; I assume that substituting the next available whitespace in this way allows the preprocessor to preserve source line and column numbers of subsequent code in the most efficient manner.

Comment: I've found confirmation that this behaviour is intended because it [maintains the location information for the rest of the compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#cpp_continuation_discarded).

Comment: Related, but different (this is not a duplicate of that): [Why both Clang and GCC only give a warning when there is a space after backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635063/why-both-clang-and-gcc-only-give-a-warning-when-there-is-a-space-after-backslash)  In this case, when the backslash and newline are removed, the space before `urn` means that the consecutive tokens are `ret` and `urn` (both identifiers) and not `return` (a keyword).  See also C11 [§5.1.1.2 Translation phases](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2) — phases 1 and 2 are relevant here.

Answer (score 3):

`-E` output is not officially specified by the standard.  It's an engineering tradeoff among several different design constraints, of which the relevant two are:

- whitespace must be inserted or deleted as necessary so that the "compiler proper" (imagine feeding the `-E` output back into `gcc -fpreprocessed` — which is what `-save-temps` does) sees the same sequence of *pp-tokens* that it would normally (without `-E`). (See C99 section 6.4 for the definition of a pp-token.)
- to the maximum extent possible, tokens should appear at the same line and column position that they did in the original source code, so that error messages and debugging information are as accurate as possible.

Here's how this applies to your examples:

```
ret\
urn 0;
```

The backslash-newline combines `ret` and `urn` into a single pp-token, which must therefore appear all together on one line in the output.  The `0` and `;`, however, should continue to be on their original line and column so that diagnostics are accurate.  So you get

```
return
    0;
```

with spaces inserted to keep the `0` in its original column.

```
ret\
   urn 0;
```

Here the backslash-newline is immediately followed by whitespace, so `ret` and `urn` do *not* have to be combined, so, again, the diagnostics are most accurate if everything stays where it originally was, and the output is

```
ret
   urn 0;
```

which looks like the backslash-newline had no effect at all.

You might find the output of `gcc -E -P` less surprising.  `-P` tells the preprocessor not to bother trying to preserve token position (and also turns off all those lines beginning with `#` in the output).  Your examples produce `return 0;` and `ret urn 0;`, both all on one line, in `-P` mode.

Finally, a word of advice: everyone who ever has to read your code (and that includes yourself six months later) will appreciate it if you *never* split a token in the middle with backslash-newline, except for very long string literals.  It's a legacy misfeature that wouldn't be included in the language if it were designed from scratch today.

Answer (score 1):

The white space is a token separator. Just because you split the line doesn't mean a white space will be ignored.

What the compiler sees is something like `ret urn;`. Which is not valid C, since it's two tokens which probably weren't defined before, nor are they in a valid expression.

Keywords must be written as a single token with no spaces.

Now, when you do :

```
  ret\
urn;
```

The backslash followed by a newline is removed in the early translation phases, and the subsequent line is appended. If the line has no white spaces at the beginning, the result is a valid token that the compiler understands as the keyword `return`.

---

Long story short, you seem to be asking about [specific behavior for GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b8bdd1600d90707). It seems like a compiler bug. Since [clang does the expected thing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ead02fbf9b20cdc) (although the line count remains the same):

```
clang -E -Wall -Wextra -Wimplicit -pedantic -std=c99 -x c main.cpp
# 1 "main.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 316 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "main.cpp" 2
int main(void) {
  ret urn 0;

}
```

It doesn't seem crucial however, since in this particular case the code will be invalid either way.

Comment: the problem I am not getting that I am getting two separate lines. Your answer is the normal behavior. That's why I am asking the question.

Comment: @Sabrina - What does *"I am getting two separate lines"* mean? Where are you supposed to be getting it from?! You write your code.

Comment: @Sabrina - Thank you for elaborating your question. See my edit please.

Comment: Any explanation why it is not joining the two lines even there is backslash + newline at the end ?

Comment: @Sabrina - Are you asking me why a program written by humans contains a bug?

Comment: So this behavior is considered as a bug.

Comment: @Sabrina - The [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/cpp/Initial-processing.html) says the lines will be joined. They are not. So I'd say it's bug material.

Comment: Can an upgrade or downgrade get rid of that presumed bug ?

Comment: @Sabrina - the version at the site I linked is GCC 6.3. So no fix up to that. I don't know if this is fixed in GCC 7.0. I must say that you seem to care way to much about that particular behavior. The resulting code is legal or illegal either way since GCC joins the lines when it should.

Comment: For some cases like obfuscation it is important. And writing portable code is also important ? or ....

Comment: @Sabrina - I highly doubt *this* will have a major affect on code portability. For obfuscation you should have eliminated **all** white spaces for maximum unreadability. So this is is again irrelevant.

Comment: I thought that at compilation it will generate error It is a weird behavior but the compiler affair that phase. the output is obvious wrong but then at execution evrything is alright !

Comment: @Sabrina - Compilation is a separate translation phase. Plus, not all tokens need white-space for separation. `int*` is two tokens.

Comment: It's [not a bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#cpp_continuation_discarded).

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the C preprocessor on `\` followed by a newline is to remove both bytes from the input.  This is done in a very early phase of the parsing. Yet the preprocessor retains the original line number for each token it sees and tries to output tokens on separate lines for the compiler to issue correct diagnostics for later phases of compilation.

For the input:

```
ret\
urn 1;
```

it may produce:

```
#line 1 "myfile.c"
return
#line 2 "myfile.c"
 1;
```

Which it may shorten as

```
return
 1;
```

Note that you can split any input line at any position with an escaped newline:

```
#inclu\
de <st\
dio.h>\

"Hello word\\
n"

for (i = 0; i < n; i+\
+)

ret\
\
\
urn;

\
r\
et\
urn\
123;\
```